# Confirming my understanding of K-Fold Cross Validation

Tags: cross-validation

I just make sure that I understand K-Fold Cross Validation correctly. In K-Fold Cross Validation we divide the dataset into k parts, in which on observation will be in a certain part for the whole process. One fold will be a test set for that iteration, and therefore, all the folds will get only a one chance to test the model. Moreover, in every iteration, we train a model with k-1 folds and test it with the remaining fold then we discard the model and we train another new model ( independent of the previous model in the first iteration) in the second iteration in a similar way as the previous iteration. We use K-Fold Cross Validation for two reasons:

1. To confirm the generalization ability of the model
   2- If the dataset is small so that if we divide it into train and test sets
   and then we train and evaluate it in the traditional way, we may
   have important information in the test set that the model didn't see
   it while training. So instead, we use K-Fold Cross Validation as
   this information will be in the training set in some iteration ( and
   for sure in the test set in another iteration)
   Is that correct ?

Comment: Yeah, you got the basics right. There are some more nuances but for starters this is good.

Comment: @usεr11852 Thanks a lot. Can you please  illustrates any missing information that I didn't mention ? Just to get a complete understanding regarding K-Fold Cross Validation.

Comment: I think you are missing points about its overall behaviour and some background; try reading "Chapter 7 Model Assessment and Selection" from [Elements of Statistical Learning](https://hastie.su.domains/ElemStatLearn/). It should cover the main background and use for you. Ask new questions if you have any particulars there.